# How do I make SQLAlchemy to generate AT TIME ZONE syntax?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table which stores UTC datetimes in Postgresql's `timestamp without time zone` column:

```
      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----
 ...
 start             | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 end               | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
```

In `psql` prompt I can request Postgres to convert the dates to a requested timezone using this syntax:

```
SELECT (start::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'AEST' FROM ...
```

How do express this syntax in SQLAlchemy? I can't do the conversion in Python because I'm going to do some `GROUP BY`s on that data.

Comment: this is NOT a duplicate. Sergey's question has nothing to do with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out!

```
    in_users_timezone = MyModel.start.op('AT TIME ZONE')('UTC').op('AT TIME ZONE')(users_time_zone)

    date_column = func.date_trunc('day', in_users_timezone).label('date')

    query = query.group_by(date_column)
```